# Google Appengine Multiple Versions Android App

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to test out an updated appengine version without ruining my live version.  The current code is:

```
themeendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new themeendpoint.Builder(
                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(),
                new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {

                    }
                }
        );


        themeendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
                endpointBuilder).build();
```

Which works fine for the default version.  I'm trying to access the "dev" version that I uploaded. I understand that normally you are supposed to add the version at the beginning like "dev.project.appspot" but I'm struggling to get this into the Android App.  I tried adding the following:

```
endpointBuilder.setRootUrl("https://dev.project.appspot.com/_ah/api/");
```

Just before creating the endpoint.  When running the app I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Hostname 'dev.project.appspot.com' was not verified
```

I'm at a loss as to how to access my non-default version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I almost had it right.  Per [this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/training/py101_2/lesson5) I need to use "-dot-" notation for HTTPS.  Plus, I was missing a small piece of the URL.  Full line of code is:

```
endpointBuilder.setRootUrl("https://dev-dot-project.appspot.com/_ah/api/");
```