# How can I connect to a non-default version of an App Engine app through the Cloud Endpoints client library for Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

The App Engine backend of my Android app is actually a non-default version of an App Engine project. However, if I connect to the App Engine backend from Android device through the Cloud Endpoints client library that is auto-generated from the backend, I see that the results retrieved indicate that I get connected to the default version of the App Engine project.

How can I make the Android application connect to the non-default version?

As always, thanks so much for your valuable advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can connect using the version specific url by using the setRootUrl method on the builder when creating the endpoint-client?

```
myEndpointBuilder.setRootUrl("https://<versioned-address>/_ah/api/")
```

Comment: Here's another question that popped up around the same time that might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275991/google-appengine-multiple-versions-android-app